# Identification of Rishon

Tags: names, rabbis, rishonim

Tosafos Rebbeinu Peretz (in Pesachim 38a) refers to הר"ר דיילקרויישא מאורליינש. Does anyone know who this is, or at least how his name is pronounced? (It looks like it could be "R' Delacroix of Orleans", but Delacroix [is not exactly a Jewish name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delacroix).)

Comment: My edition of Pesachim 38a says R'y M'Orlean's, not Delacroix.  Which edition of the gemara are you using?

Comment: @AdamMosheh this is in [Tosafos Rebbeinu Peretz](http://www.otzar.org/wotzar/Book.aspx?144521&), not in Tosafos printed in the margin of the Gemara.

Comment: Here you can copy and paste: http://www.otzar.org/wotzar/pagetext.aspx?bookid=144521&pageid=P0083&sec=2&pagenum=82

Answer (score 8):

Excerpt from R' Yaakov Lipschitz's [foreword to תוספות שאנץ](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22715&st=&pgnum=24):

> שבתוספות שאנץ על הגליון כמו בתוספות תר"פ, ישנו פירוש ״מהר״ד דלקרוישא", חכם בלתי ידוע במקום אחר, ומצאתיו רק פעמים אחדות בתוספות תלמיד רבינו פרץ למסכת פסחים

Comment: According to the footnote in the link, it's the same person as הר"ד דיילקרויישא מאורליינש.